# How to model timeseries temperature data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, seasonality, anomaly-detection

I would like to model a timeseries consisting of internal temperature data of a greenhouse, collected at 15 min interval and then use it to make predictions in the future.

This is how my data looks like: [image]

The graph shows seasonality (day/night).

I've been thinking about regression models (specifically polynomial regressions) to obtain some sort of function but so far I haven't obtained satisfactory results.

I am not an expert in machine learning. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Why not use standard time series methods to account for seasonality? Using polynomials does not strike me as a good idea (although I'm not much of an expert on TS).

Comment: My first thought would be to use Fourier series as this appears to be a combination of periodic functions